# Как называется подход к организации файловой системы запрещающий наличие файлов и директорий на одном уровне?

Tags: файлы, файловая-система

Как называется подход к организации файловой системы запрещающий наличие файлов и директорий на одном уровне?

Comment: Спросите это у того, кто решил вдруг так делать

Comment: @Mike А в чём конкретно минус такой идеи?

Comment: никаких минусов не вижу. так же как и не вижу смысла создавать искусственные запреты на ровном месте. в каких то случаях такой принцип вытекает из самой задачи. например при индексации с помощью файловой системы, когда на промежуточных уронях дерева просто не может быть листьев. Но и есть куча случаев, когда файлы абсолютно логично располагаются в перемешку с каталогами

Comment: @Mike 1. Так красиво и аккуратно, весь несортируемый мусор можно сгрести хотя бы в etc внутри каждой такой директории. 2. Надо меньше думать при переходе по директориям - видишь папки значит ещё не приехал. 3. Пару раз я путался в линуксе где зачастую отсутсвуют расширения файлов, т.е. искал папку вместо файла. Опять же надо меньше думать - видишь файл значит ниже не провалишься - всё кругом только файлы, проще ориентироваться. 4. Проще становится управление chmod.

Comment: 5. Ну и самое главное - жёсткое отделение мух от котлет. Красивые аккуратные деревья - снизу ветки сверху листья, а не заросли.

Comment: вопрос не в удобстве. вы спросили как называется такой принцип. А он никак не называется. потому что никому не нужно это как то называть.

Comment: тем более, что удобство вещь относительная. вам удобно так, мне по другому, еще кому то по третьему. Мне вот удобнее писать cat /etc/passwd, а не cat /etc/other_files/passwd. И кстати проблема что искали директорию а нашли файл вообще надуманная. ставите mc и забываете обо всех этих проблемах.

Comment: @Mike Кстати сама папка `etc` в корне так и появилась. Но мысль дальше корня не пошла.

Comment: ну это логично "настройки->пользователи", а не "настройки->единичные_файлы->пользователи", сущность в середине цепочки искусственная получается и не все можно классифицировать. А когда что то нельзя классифицировать появляется "прочее" и тогда уже точно концов не найдешь. Я вижу программу, думаю что у нее должны быть настройки, смотрю нет ли в etc что то с ее названием.  И нахожу либо файл либо каталог. А если там будет иерархия, то я буду полдня придумывать к какому классу ее стоило бы относить или запускаю find по всему дереву, потому что не знаю к чему ее относить и к чему ее отнесли авторы